# not getting the entry_id

Tags: add-on

I am new to expressionengine,
I created a module that just print a form on a page
my method is:

`if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
                 $data[$key] = $this->EE->input->post($key);
            }
            print_r($data);
        }
        // Find the entry_id of the auction to add the form for
        if (ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('entry_id'))
        {
            $entry_id = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('entry_id');
        }`

```
    // Build an array to hold the form's hidden fields
    $hidden_fields = array(
        "entry_id" => $entry_id,
    );

    // Build an array with the form data
    $form_data = array(
        "id"            => $this->EE->TMPL->form_id,
        "class"         => $this->EE->TMPL->form_class,
        "hidden_fields" => $hidden_fields,
        'action'        => "",
    );
    // Fetch contents of the tag pair, ie, the form contents
    $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;

    $form = $this->EE->functions->form_declaration($form_data) .
    $tagdata . "</form>";

    return $form;
}
```

above mentioned method returning form but with empty entry_id.
How can i get the entry_id and how can I remove the form action?

Thank you